# Why does R sometimes let me use get(string) to refer to a data.table and sometimes not?

Tags: r, data.table

I often need to conduct the same operation on different `data.table`s in R, using a `for` loop that runs through the object names of the `data.table`s, passed as strings, and the `get` command to fetch the object that the string refers to. So for example:

```
for (dt in c("first_data_table", "second_data_table", "third_data_table")) {
  (get(dt))[, my_new_column := "I am adding a new column."]
}
```

Much of the time, this works fine. But sometimes, it doesn't: R simply does not conduct the operation inside the `for` loop on any of the `data.table`s I've told it to, even though it doesn't produce any error or warning. I have never been able to figure out when or why the language decides to cooperates with this syntax, and when it fails to. Moreover, I've recently found that when R refuses to execute the command, I can bizarrely coax it into doing so by simply adding and deleting an empty column to each `data.table` by name ahead of time, like so:

```
first_data_table[, test_column := TRUE
  ][, test_column := NULL]
second_data_table[, test_column := TRUE
  ][, test_column := NULL]
third_data_table[, test_column := TRUE
  ][, test_column := NULL]
# Now, for some reason, creating and removing these empty columns makes that code from above work
for (dt in c("first_data_table", "second_data_table", "third_data_table")) {
  (get(dt))[, my_new_column := "I am adding a new column."]
}
```

Does anyone here have any idea why `data.table` is exhibiting such strange behavior, and whether there's a more sensible way to ensure it will function correctly than just adding and deleting random columns before my `for` loops? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. For what it's worth, I'm working on a Windows machine, running R version 4.0.2 and `data.table` version 1.13.0.

Comment: Put your data.tables in a list. You should not use get for this.

Comment: Thanks, Roland. Why is ```get``` a poor choice here, aside from the fact that R doesn't seem to want to execute it some of the time? It's still slightly annoying to have to create a list of my ```data.table```s in order to run a ```for``` loop, and then I guess use ```list2env``` to replace each existing ```data.table``` with its counterpart from the list after the loop has completed...

Comment: If you want to run a loop over a bunch of data.tables (or any objects really), they should be put in a list when you create them and they should *remain* in that list. There is no reason whatsoever to take them ever out of the list, except if you combine all of the list into one data.table.

Comment: I think you misunderstand @Roland's comment, what he's suggesting is replacing `for (dt in c("first_data_table", "second_data_table", "third_data_table"))` with `for (dt in list(first_data_table, second_data_table, third_data_table))`. then `dt` will itself be a `data.table`, and `get` is unnecessary

Comment: But that syntax won’t actually modify the object in my global environment called ```first_data_table```, will it?

Comment: Answering my own question: Yes, that actually does work. I'm still curious why ```get(string)``` seems to behave so inconsistently, but will use ```list``` going forward.

Comment: You are still not understanding. You should not even have an object `first_data_table` in the global environment. It should happily coexist with `second_data_table` etc. in a list.

Comment: Apart from the fact, that you should take @Roland's advice and use lists rather than `get` I can't reproduce your issue. Your code works fine for me even though I'm not adding columns beforehand.